# How to make dropdown appear over content and not push content down?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, slide

I can't figure out how to make the dropdown slide over the content below. The content is just a big dark box right now, but it still does get pushed down instead of staying in place. How can I make the dropdown slide over this content instead of pushing the page content down?

```
            <div class="menu-icon" onclick="myFunction(this)">
              <div class="bar1"></div>
              <div class="bar2"></div>
              <div class="bar3"></div>
            </div>
          <div style="display:none;" class="nav-dropdown">
            <a href="#">How It Works</a>
            <a href="#">FAQ</a>
            <a href="#">PRIVACY AND SECURITY</a>
            <a href="#">SUPPORT</a>
            <a style="border-bottom: none;" href="#">GET EARLY ACCESS</a>
          </div>

These script tags are for clicking the dropdown to make it toggle slide.
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".menu-icon").click(function() {
            $(".nav-dropdown").slideToggle();
          });
        });
      </script>
      <script>
        function myFunction(x) {
          x.classList.toggle("change");
        }
      </script>


    .nav-dropdown {
      background-color: rgb(27, 27, 31);
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column nowrap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and it's working as expected.
What is the issue?

Here is an example

```css
 .nav-dropdown {
      background-color: rgb(27, 27, 31);
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column nowrap;
      color:white;
      position: absolute;;
      left:0;
      top:100%;
      z-index:999;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
     .menu-icon {
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       background-color: blue;
       color: white;
       position:relative;
     }
  </style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu-icon").click(function(){
    $(".nav-dropdown").slideToggle();
  });
  
});
</script>
<script>
  function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="menu-icon" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    click here
    <div style="display:none;" class="nav-dropdown">
        <a href="#">How It Works</a>
        <a href="#">FAQ</a>
        <a href="#">PRIVACY AND SECURITY</a>
        <a href="#">SUPPORT</a>
        <a style="border-bottom: none;" href="#">GET EARLY ACCESS</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letrase</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes this is what it does currently. If I have content under it, the dropdown pushed the content down the page. I want to figure out how to make the dropdown drop over it, instead of pushing all the content down the page. My initial thought was using z-index in some way.